# Developing webservice client on JDK 1.6 and needs to be compatible with JDK 1.5.03

Tags: java, web-services, client, compatibility, java-5

I'm trying to run webservice client on JDK 1.5 and it gives me many errors such as classnotfound exception, nosuchmethod... Is it possible to add some libs such as jax-ws, axis... and run it under JDK 1.5?

What's the best approach? I have NetBeans 6.9.1 on JDK 1.6, created project compatible for JDK 1.5. It works on my machine but on other with only 1.5 doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to develop for JDK1.5, then download JDK1.5, and use it to develop your application. NetBeans allows using another JDK than the one it comes with.

You're shooting yourself in the foot by targetting JDK1.5 and developing on JDK1.6.

Comment: I did, but i tried to run it on another machine with has only 1.5 and it gave me exceptions.

Comment: Then you probably don't run with the same classpath on your dev machine and on the other machine. Fix the classpath.

Comment: Ok. I made a project on jdk1.5, and now i run it on 1.5 too. Getting:java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:33)
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:128)
        at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:108)
        at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:57)

Comment: Compare the classpaths, and find what's missing on the second machine. You probably forgot to add jaxws-rt-xxx.jar (at least) to the classpath.

Comment: It stucks at 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.getNamespaceContext()Lcom/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/xni/NamespaceContext;
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.<init>(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:98)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl.getXMLStreamReaderImpl(XMLInputFactoryImpl.java:267)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl.createXMLStreamReader(XMLInputFactoryImpl.java:140)
        at ...
probably libraries not compatible with each other?

Comment: If it runs on one machine with a given JDK, it must run on another with the same JDK, if you use the same classpath. Take the classpath and libraries on the first machine, and use the same on the second.

Comment: i know that, but its not working on same machine either. When i create project in netbeans wants to have jdk1.6 (cant run nb on 1.5). and when i change run target path to 1.5 then gave me all this exceptions.

Comment: i finally got all jars to classpath, when i run WS Client, i got: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerErrorCaused by: A WebService annotation is not present on class: java.net.URL

i generated it with wsimport.

Comment: You should ask another question, because your initial question doesn't have much to do with the situation you're in.